# Are kernels launched from different classes on the default cuda stream

Tags: c++, class, cuda

Consider, we have the following consecutive calls:

```
//our_class.cuh   
#include "myClass.cuh"
#include "yourClass.cuh"

class our_class{   
private:   
    const int myFoods = 1000;   
    const int yourSleep = 2000;   

public:   
    int * d_food;
    int * d_sleep;
    myClass * obj_1;
    yourClass * obj_2;

    void member_function_1();
};

//our_class.cu        
#include "our_class.cuh"
void our_class::member_function_1(){        
    obj_1 = new myClass();        
    obj_2 = new yourClass();    
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_food, sizeof(int)*myFoods );   
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_sleep, sizeof(int)*yourSleep );   
           
    obj_1->eating_food( d_food, myFoods );
    obj_2->just_sleeping_bro( d_food, d_sleep, yourSleep );   
}       

//myClass.cuh
class myClass{
public:
    void eating_food( int* d_food, int myFoods );
};

// myClass.cu
#include "myClass.cuh"
__global__ void food_party( int * d_food ){
    // have that food party
    // d_food changes here
}

void myClass::eating_food( int * d_food, int myFoods ){
    food_party<<< myFoods, 1 >>>( d_food );
}

// yourClass.cuh
class yourClass{
public:
    void just_sleeping_bro( int * d_food, int * d_sleep, int yourSleep );
};

// yourClass.cu
#include "yourClass.cuh"

__global__ void sleeping_beauty( int * d_food, int * d_sleep ){
    // d_sleep depends on d_food bro!!!
}

void yourClass::just_sleeping_bro( int * d_food, int * d_sleep, int yourSleep ){
    sleeping_beauty<<< yourSleep, 1 >>>( d_food, d_sleep );
}
```

As you might have observed, d_sleep depends on d_food.
So, my question is, are food_party and sleeping_beauty kernels on the default stream.
Or should we put a device synchronize command at the end of food_party so that the math is all correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on these launches:

```
sleeping_beauty<<< yourSleep, 1 >>>( d_food, d_sleep );

food_party<<< myFoods, 1 >>>( d_food );
```

those kernels are being launched into the default stream.  The [kernel launch configuration syntax](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration) has 4 parts:

```
<<<grid_dimensions, block_dimensions, shared_memory_bytes, stream>>>
```

Since you are not explicitly passing a `stream` argument, you know they are being launched into the default stream.

regardless of whether they go into the default stream or not, you can be certain that if you launch them into the **same** stream, then [stream semantics](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#streams) dictate they will execute in issue order.  For example if you issued   `food_party` before `sleeping_beauty`, you can be certain that the `food_party`  kernel ends before `sleeping_beauty` the  kernel begins.  Furthermore, you can be certain that any changes that `food_party` made to the array referenced by `d_food` will be properly visible to the code executing in the subsequent `sleeping_beauty`  kernel.  No intervening sync should be needed to ensure that consistency.

Comment: Perhaps worth reminding OP that it's the default stream _on the current device_.